# jQuery - dynamic table calculations break when adding .toFixed(1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my efforts to solve a rounding problem I've broken the dynamic updating of totals that was previously working fine.

If you look at this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/73Jzc/1/

you will see as you change the select menu and add new rows and data the totals for moderate and high update dynamically. If you change a selection from high to moderate they continue to update.

I updated the script to fix a rounding issue in the totals which you can see at this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/73Jzc/2/

All I did was change:

```
$('#textfield6').val(tot.moderate);
$('#textfield7').val( tot.high );
```

to:

```
$('#textfield6').val(tot.moderate.toFixed(1));
$('#textfield7').val( tot.high.toFixed(1) );
```

and that appears to have stopped the dynamic totals from updating and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define `tot` with default-values for high and moderate:

```
var tot = {high:0,moderate:0};
```

otherwise you will get an error when either *high* or *moderate* isn't selected in any list

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle - I was doing that in a previous version of my script but it somehow got removed along the way without me noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that tot.moderate or tot.high exists before calling .toFixed(). If there are no moderate or high rows, you get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toFixed' of undefined